# How to Pass values form One html Page to Another html Page javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I pass values from one html page to another html page javascript

For example:

**Page1.html page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>arasu</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  #popupbox{
  margin: 0; 
  margin-left: 40%; 
  margin-right: 40%;
  margin-top: 50px; 
  padding-top: 10px; 
  width: 20%; 
  height: 150px; 
  position: absolute; 
  background: #FBFBF0; 
  border: solid #000000 2px; 
  z-index: 9; 
  font-family: arial; 
  visibility: hidden; 
  }
  </style>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  function login(showhide){
    if(showhide == "show"){
        document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="visible";
    }else if(showhide == "hide"){
        document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="hidden"; 
    }
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div > 
<form name="login" action="AgaramAnimation.html" method="get">
<center>Username:</center>
<center><input name="username" size="14" /></center>
<center>Password:</center>
<center><input name="password" type="password" size="14" /></center>
<center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" /></center>
</form>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

here i enter two values user name and password when i click submit button the popup will closed and values pass to another page java script given below .

**Page2.html**

```
function gettingvalues()
         {            
            var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
            var connectionstring = "Data Source="";Initial Catalog="";User ID="";Password="";Provider=""";
            connection.Open(connectionstring);
            var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
            rs.Open("select * from logindetails where username='" **+ username +** "' and password= '" **+ password +** "'", connection);
            if (!rs.eof) {
                document.getElementById("").innerHTML = "";   }
            else {
                alert('please enter valid username and password');
            }
            connection.close;
        }
```

Pls help me..........

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your two pages are on the same domain, you can use localStorage.

Popup.html:

```
var user = prompt('user name', '');
var password = prompt('password', '');
localStorage.user = user;
localStorage.password = password;
```

Then back in the main page:

```
var user = localStorage.user;
var password = localStorage.password;
```

**Note 1**: I won't comment on security (other than to say of course don't do it like I've done it above!)

**Note 2**: localStorage is only about 92% supported: http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage

Answer (score 0):

If `Main.html` has opened `Popup.html` with `window.open()`, then the Popup.html page can have a reference to its opening window (the window of `Main.html`) using `window.opener`. It could thus call a `setCredentials` callback function defined in `Main.html` using

```
window.opener.setCredentials(...);
```

Example:

in Main.html:

```
// callback function called by the popup
function setCredentials(login, password) {
    // do what you want with the login and password
}
```

in Popup.html

```
// function called when the form is submitted
function login(login, password) {
    window.opener.setCredentials(login, password);
    window.close();
}
```

Comment: it's difficult to make examples of something like this with a web editor like jsfiddle, since it requires separate html pages to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the window that opened your new window (called the parent window) via `window.parent` and then execute your javascript using that object.

Here is an example of forcing a parent page to refresh using this: [[1]Forcing parent page refresh through javascript](http://moeyae.wordpress.com/2006/10/14/forcing-parent-page-refresh-through-javascript/)

So in your case you could have say variables for username and password in your js like this and you could set them in the popup window like so:

```
//parent window
username = "";
password = "";

....

//popup window
window.parent.username = enteredUsername;
window.parent.password = enteredPassword;
```

Comment: Popup window is Separate Html.Page. here is my question when i click a link in main.html, popup window open i enter username and password then popup window must close and username and password pass to java script in main html.

Comment: Yes. You have your main page, from inside your main page you pop up a new html page for getting password info. Your new html page contains this reference to the parent page that opened it via window.parent. Before you close the popup window you set the username and password in the parent page and then continue in the main parent page.

Comment: @vassilo: window.parent is the parent page of a frame in a frameset. Nothing to do with popups. window.opener is the window that opened the popup. See https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/DOM/window.parent and my answer

Comment: Using window.parent works to return the parent window for a popup. If it is more "correct" to use window.opener then sure so be it. Both will give the same functionality in this case.